# How can I run Scheme on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, scheme, lisp

I'm wondering how to run simple Scheme code on Visual Studio Code.

I've installed an extension called Scheme, but what is the next step..

I didn't find any details on the extension about how to run the code or the developer's contact ...

Comment: Just a guess, but the extension might just be for editing, not running.

Comment: And it is strange as Scheme so light that its interpreter can be embedded as VSCode plugin. Where can I found some easy to follow tutorial on VSCode plugins writing? Not a full manual, but easy to start intro.

Comment: Maybe someone wants to help with plugin implementation& https://github.com/ponyatov/VSCheme

Answer (score 5):

Compiling Scheme on VSCode is quite easy by now.

Install the [Code Runner extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner).

For setting it up:

- Open User Settings (`ctrl + ,` by default)
- Search for `Code-runner: Executor Map By File Extension`.
- Press "Edit in settings.json"
- Add the following:

```
"code-runner.executorMapByFileExtension": {
    ".scm": "racket"
}
```

- Run the code directly with `ctrl + alt + n` or from the Command Palette (`ctrl + shift + p`) with `Run Code`

Comment: I followed your exact instructions but I'm getting the following error `'csi' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: I have the same issue as @User2585 : 

I added: 
`"code-runner.executorMapByFileExtension": {  ".scm": "racket",  ".rkt": "racket" }, "code-runner.executorMap": {  "racket": "C:\\Program iles\\Racket\\Racket.exe tete $fullFileName" }
`
to settings.json 


**Trying to run the file yields:**


`[Running] csi -script "c:\Users\olivierH\-dev-\scheme\scheme-1.rkt"
'csi' is not recognized as an internal or external command ...`

Comment: Instead of the above, I used the following which worked: 
```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
        "scheme": "racket"
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

From looking at the [github source](https://github.com/rebornix/vscode-scheme) it seems it only provide basic syntax highlighting support. Thus VSC is slightly better than Notepad, but not much.

To run you need to start one of the available scheme systems and run the file. It might be a way to do that from VSC, but it's not included in the extension.

I would have opted for [DrRacket](https://racket-lang.org/) which is a IDE and an implementation of many Scheme standard languages. It can help you expand macros, debug and profile your code in the same place. Another great alternative is [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), but it requires a little more effort to set up. I have yet to hear about other alternatives.

Comment: Thanks! I used racket before.. but I'm more favor of VSC

Comment: You can also use SublimeText 2/3 with SublimeREPL & Scheme

Comment: off topic hand not helping

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to use VS Code because it's a good IDE (better than DRacket in terms of completion (parens, etc) and code navigation, I just discovered [scheme on repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/scheme).

Doesn't appear that you can debug in Scheme. But it's a good start. (I'm getting the csi error as well).