# How can I run Scheme in Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, scheme, visual-studio-code

I'm reading Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs by H. Abelson et al.
The programming language Scheme is used for the examples and the exercises.
I'm used to Visual Studio Code for editing my code on Ubuntu 20.04 and I'm trying to run my code written in Scheme through the extension [Code Runner](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner).
I tried to adopt some [recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49183001/how-can-i-run-scheme-on-visual-studio-code) for configuring the plug-in to run the Scheme code in the mit-scheme interpreter :

```
sudo apt install mit-scheme
```

and

```
config code-runner
"code-runner.executorMapByFileExtension": {
    ".scm": "racket",
    ".rkt": "racket",
    ".ss": "racket",
    ".sch": "racket",
},
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "racket" : "/usr/bin/mit-scheme"  
},
```

When I attempt to run a portion of Scheme code I wrote the temporary file is generated by Code Runner but an error is returned when it attempts to interpret it:

```
[Running] csi -script "/home/mat650/Desktop/tempCodeRunnerFile.scm"
/bin/sh: 1: csi: not found

[Done] exited with code=127 in 0.019 seconds
```

The bash reports:

```
<< Command 'csi' not found, but can be  
<< installed with:
<< sudo apt install chicken-bin
```

hence, I installed as suggested chicken-bin

```
sudo apt install chicken-bin
```

But nothing has changed and Code Runner still exits with the same error.

So, any help in configuring the scheme interpreter to run in Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu 20.04 will be much appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- launch a terminal inside vscode (Ctrl-Shift+´), and in there run your scheme interpreter:

  e.g. $mit-scheme
- in your editor window, above the terminal, you edit the code. Select/mark the code you want to test, and from Menu->Terminal->"Run selected code" you send it down to the scheme interpreter running in the terminal.

Attention flatpakers: this does not work with flatpak vscode as flatpaks are sandboxed and you cannot access outside the sandbox. The snap vscode version does it "correctly".

Comment: This solved my problem without the need for any plug-in configuration. I will just add a key-binding for 'Run selected code' to make it always available without any click. Thanks.

Comment: I added a simple scheme code formatter to https://github.com/paines/chicken-code-formatter which works on chicken code and vscode (in theory with any editor).